# How do I display data from firebase in a flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've looked at some similar question and tried to change the code but the data still won't show. I've watch a few tutorials and I've got this far.
This is my code.

```
 export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    dateItems: [],
    loading: false,
  }

  unsubscribe = null;

  async getAppointment() {
    const dateList = [];
    var snapshot = await firebase.firestore()
      .collection('appointment')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .get()

    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      dateList.push({
        key: doc.id,
        date: doc.data().date,
        createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
      });
      this.setState({
        dateItems: dateList,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
    console.log(dateList);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAppointment();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View >
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Appointments</Text>
            <Button
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Booking')} title="Add"
            />
          </View>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dateItems}
            renderItem={(item, index) => (
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{item.date}</Text>
                <Text>Created: {item.createdAt}</Text>
                <View style={styles.hr}></View>
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The data shows in an array in the console

```
Array [
  Object {
    "createdAt": t {
      "nanoseconds": 467000000,
      "seconds": 1591023433,
    },
    "date": t {
      "nanoseconds": 478000000,
      "seconds": 1592740813,
    },
    "key": "Qlaq8Nd5GYaxFYr9M6Iq",
  },
  Object {
    "createdAt": t {
      "nanoseconds": 31000000,
      "seconds": 1591020391,
    },
    "date": t {
      "nanoseconds": 859000000,
      "seconds": 1593327612,
    },
    "key": "ZsP2pBcNNgb4Nj6Jrpce",
  },
]
```

I need to show the date and not the timestamp for both date and createdAt. i don't know where I can implement this.

Comment: I think, you are getting issue here `snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      dateList.push({
        key: doc.id,
        date: doc.data().date,
        createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
      });` try adding toJSON() to each line.

Comment: I get a `ReferenceError: toJSON is not defined` or `TypeError: doc.data(...).date.toJSON is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting dates in Javascript can be very messy since you get into all sorts of complications with timezones, etc.

But in general, to start with, you'll want a new `Date` object. To get that, you would do:

```
const date = new Date(doc.data().date.seconds * 1000)
```

This is because the `Date` constructor takes (as one option) the number of milliseconds since 1970 as its argument.

However, this will only give you a `Date` object, and `console.log` will return a very long string like "Mon Jun 01 2020 07:57:13 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)". To format it, you want `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```
const dateObj = new Date(doc.data().date.seconds * 1000)
const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(dateObj) // "6/1/2020"
```

If you want to have more granular control than that over the date format, look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) or, to make your life much easier, use something like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

If you're ok with the default `en-US` formatting (or any other locale), your code will end up looking something like the following. I'm not sure why you are calling `setState` inside every loop of the `forEach` statement, but assuming you can save that until `dateList` is fully built, you can use `map` instead, which is more efficient:

```
const dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US') 
const dateList = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
  const dateObj = new Date(doc.data().date.seconds * 1000)
  const createdAtObj = new Date(doc.data().createdAt.seconds * 1000)
  return {
    key: doc.id,
    date: dateFormat.format(dateObj),
    createdAt: dateFormat.format(createdAtObj)
  }
 });

 this.setState({
    dateItems: dateList,
    loading: false,
 })
```

Comment: I tried your code, the only change in the console `Object {
    "createdAt": "5/29/2020",
    "date": "12/10/1815",
    "key": "0kGa3D7zpDmdP43q5RAy",
  },`.  The data is still not showing on the screen.

Comment: You just need braces `{}` inside your `renderItem` function call, then you should be good: `renderItem={({item, index}) ...`

Comment: The data shows, and there's a warning: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: One more thing, how can I specify to only show data made by the current user?

Comment: That completely depends on how you’ve set up your accounts and how the data is formatted. If every element of `snapshot.docs` has a `user` field, you can do something like `datelist = snapshot.docs.filter((doc) => (doc.user == currentUser)).map((doc) => ...` You should post a separate question if you can’t figure it out after messing around with it.